# Does Brains over brawn Factotum skill apply for grapple and initiative?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Brains over Brawn states

> Brains over Brawn (Ex): At 3rd level, you gain your Intelligence bonus
>   as a modiﬁer on Strength checks, Dexterity checks, and checks
>   involving skills based on Strength or Dexterity, such as Hide, Climb,
>   and Jump.

My master states that maybe I'm over-reading, Rolling Grapple isn't a stregth check. So, community, help us out! =)

I'm almost certain that he's right, I think that for making this valid it should say

> Brains over Brawn (Ex): At 3rd level, you gain your Intelligence bonus
>   as a modiﬁer on *Strength-based* checks and *Dexterity-based* checks

So, reiteration here: Brains over brawn Factotum ability applies for grapple and initiative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Initiative

d20SRD > Combat > [Initiative](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/initiative.htm)

> At the start of a battle, each combatant makes an initiative check. **An initiative check is a Dexterity check.** Each character...

An initiative check *is* a Dexterity check, and therefore benefits from Brains Over Brawn. The factotum adds his Intelligence bonus to initiative checks (in addition to his Dexterity bonus and any other bonus that might apply, e.g. Improved Initiative).

## Grappling

d20SRD > Combat > Special Attacks > [Grapple](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#grapple)

> Repeatedly in a grapple, you need to make opposed grapple checks against an opponent. **A grapple check is like a melee attack roll.** Your attack bonus on a grapple check...

A grapple check is *like* a melee attack roll, which itself is not any kind of ability check but a different sort of roll entirely, so Brains Over Brawn does not apply. Cunning Insight *does* apply to attack rolls, but even so, a grapple check is only *like* a melee attack roll, not actually a melee attack roll, so Cunning Insight does not apply to that either. Factota do not gain any ability that adds Intelligence bonus to grapple checks.